# JIRA Builtin Script Listener - Create a sub-task. - How to set assignee?

Tags: groovy, components, jira, jira-plugin

I am using **JIRA Builtin Script Listener** - Create a sub-task. to create subtasks for Dev and QA for every story and bug in JIRA.

I would like the subtasks to be always assigned to user "Virtual QA". It seems that I have to do this through **Additional issue actions** field.
I am trying to use:

```
issue.summary = ('QA: ' + issue.summary)
issue.assignee = 'Virtual QA'
```

This works only if I use only the first line to set the subtask summary but when I add the second line the script does not run. Can you please help me to solve it?

I was not able to help myself using the official documentation on: https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Built-In+Scripts

Comment: no error anywhere on the screen when i save the script or create a ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation and a hundred text tickets this works :)

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
issue.summary = ('QA: ' + issue.summary)
issue.setAssignee(ComponentAccessor.getUserUtil().getUser('qa'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass user object instead of string, same question here
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/66562/set-assignee-to-some-specific-user-in-post-function-script

Comment: As Georgiy Senenkov Jul 03 '12 at 07:51 AM said, neither of the proposed solutions work. I tried all the described solutions and it did not work for me.

Comment: what is the jira version?